# Remove tag episerver-cms

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

There's only one question with the tag [episerver-cms](/questions/tagged/episerver-cms)

There is a tag [episerver](/questions/tagged/episerver) already in use, which that single question also uses.

Should we just remove or create a synonym for the [episerver-cms](/questions/tagged/episerver-cms) tag?

---

I can't vote for a synonym because although i'm familiar with episerver i've not asked or answered questions on it.

---

Original question retagged to remove that tag.

[Render EPiServer XForm on usual page, not inherited from EPiServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335005/render-episerver-xform-on-usual-page-not-inherited-from-episerver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you retag the question to remove the [episerver-cms](/questions/tagged/episerver-cms) tag, it will age away on its own in (I think) 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Since [EPiServer](http://www.episerver.com/en/Products/) has more products than *just* a CMS, I don't see any harm in having more specific tags.

Comment: The episerver tag has this description: "EPiServer is an ASP.NET-based CMS (Content Management System)" If we have more specific tags should this one have it's description changed? To me it says that EPiserver only do a CMS.

Comment: @George: Yes, that description does look too specific for that tag.